# Getting Empty Results For 'COUNT'/'GROUP BY' MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I am getting similar problem as the issue posted here: [How can I get a non empty result set when using select, group by and count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644761/how-can-i-get-a-non-empty-result-set-when-using-select-group-by-and-count)

However, the solution given is slower, mentioned by the answerer. I was just wondering if there any alternative solution without compromising performance?

Also, I don't understand why a query like:

```
SELECT
`a`, `b`, COUNT(*) as `c`
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `status` = 1
GROUP BY `a`,`b`
```

will return empty result where only without the 'GROUP BY' part it shows expected result with 0 as count value? Is this can be a possible mysql bug?

I have also found a discussion on mysql bug portal, with similar issue, here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26087

But this discussion isn't matured enough to get a suitable answer, I guess.

My Questions:

- Is this could be a possible mysql bug?
- Is is possible to have a better alternative solution than the given one(the link at the beginning)? If yes, how?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited the question with my exact questions, hope this explain better now.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a MySQL bug.

An aggregation query will return one row per group that is encountered.  Without a `group by`, there is one group -- the entire table.  I admit this is a bit tricky, because there is still one group, even when there are no rows in the table.

With a `group by`, there is one row per group.  If there are no rows in a group, then the group does not appear.  In your case, the query:

```
SELECT `a`, `b`, COUNT(*) as `c`
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `status` = 1
```

Will return one row, with two `NULL`s followed by `0`.

The same query with:

```
GROUP BY `a`,`b`
```

will return no rows because there are no rows to form groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what about the other question, getting a better solution where at least I can get a row instead of empty result? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap COUNT with IFNULL? `\`a\`, \`b\`, IFNULL(COUNT(*) as \`c\`, '')`

Comment: @KyleChadha . . . `COUNT()` never returns `NULL` within a `SELECT`, so the `IFNULL()` is useless.  A `NULL` value is returned when there is no row.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it isn't a MySQL bug. But you can define a derived table first and then count its results. I think this behavior is because of the hierarchy of MySQL operations.

```
SELECT
`a`, `b`, COUNT(*) as `c`
FROM ( SELECT `a`, `b`
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `status` = 1
GROUP BY `a`,`b`) t
```

Comment: Still returns empty to me :(