# Left Joining With Some default values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, left-join

I am trying to build a query which will take some default values and will left join with a table. This just to allow at least one result in case the main query(2nd) one doesn't match to any row and thus might return empty result set [as mentioned on my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549331/getting-empty-results-for-count-group-by-mysql-query).

my query is pretty much as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    (SELECT 'test' as `column1`, 'test' as `column2`, 0 as c) t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT `column1`, `column2`, COUNT(*) as c
        FROM `my_table`
        WHERE `status` = 1
        GROUP BY column1, column2) t2
)
```

Its showing up a mysql error on phpmyadmin as below:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't2 )' at line 7
```

What is wrong with the query please?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2, coalesce(t2.c, 0)
FROM (SELECT 'test' as `column1`, 'test' as `column2`, 0 as c
     ) t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT `column1`, `column2`, COUNT(*) as c
      FROM `my_table`
      WHERE `status` = 1
      GROUP BY column1, column2
     ) t2
     on t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 = t2.column2;
```

Your query is incomplete.  It doesn't have an `on` clause, for instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clue. However, modifying my query like the one you gave, I am facing another issue "#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='" . The both column is of "latin1_swedish_ci" Collation type. How I can fix this error please?

Comment: Sounds like your database collation differs from your table collation.  Use the `COLLATE` keyword.  The place to start is here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collations.html.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot in fixing that issue. However, I am having another issue now about the manually made table t1. Though the query works as a normal query, My implementation is inside a 'trigger' and there its throwing error. Its saying "Unknown column t1.column1 in on clause" . Does trigger not accept manually made table? How to recover from this please?

Comment: @Rana . . . There is no such limitation in triggers.  I would suggest that you ask another question where you post the trigger code you are using.